# How to skip block popup window.open()

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, popup, chrome-browser

I am using bellow code. It seems works fine in firefox and IE But not in Crome browser for skip popup blocking.

```
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl('custom/index/addcountry') ?>', {
    asynchronous: false,
    method: 'post',
    parameters: str,
    onSuccess: function(respo) {
        window.open(respo.responseText,'_blank' );
    }
});
```

**In Crome browser popup block how to skip popup blocking.**

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested it but try this:

```
var redirectWindow = window.open('some url', '_blank' );
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl('custom/index/addcountry') ?>', {
       asynchronous: false,
       method: 'post',
       parameters: str,
       onSuccess: function(respo) {
           redirectWindow.location;
       }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72hs3vrp/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this not works for me. i got redirect url from ajax responce.